# SelectList not showing my values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Can some one tell me why this bit of code

```
@Html.DropDownList("priority2", new SelectList(new[] { 1,2,3 }, Model.Priority))
```

gives me a fine dropdown to choose between 1,2,3

but this

```
@Html.DropDownList("priority", new SelectList(new [] {
 new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "1. Priority" },
 new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "2. Priority" },
 new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "3. Priority" } }, 
Model.Priority))
```

gives me 3 options all saying 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'

What have I done wrong?

Comment: maybe u need define value and display members

Comment: Because your creating a pointless second `SelectList` from the first one, but not setting the `Value` and `Text` properties. It would need to be `....Model.Priority), "Value", "Text"))` -

Comment: ah! Pointless was the word. Or I could just remove the new 'SelectList()'

Comment: All you need is `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Priority, new List<SelectListItem>{ new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "1. Priority" }, new ..... })` but you really should be generating the `SelectList` in the controller, not the view.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. But I think in this case it would be overdoing things to create the SelectList in the controller. It is only a list of Integers I want to represent with some text instead. Not data I pull form the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectList()` constructor uses reflection to generate `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Where you do not specify the `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` properties, internally the method uses the `.ToString()` value of the object in the collection.

In the first example, you have a an array of values types so `.ToString()` outputs "1", "2" etc.

In the second example, you have an array of `SelectListItem` and its `.ToString()` method outputs "SelectListItem".

For the 2nd example to generate the correct html, it would need to be

```
@Html.DropDownList("priority", new SelectList(new []
{
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "1. Priority" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "2. Priority" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "3. Priority" }
}, "Value", "Text", Model.Priority))
```

where the second parameter `"Value"` specifies the property name of `SelectListItem` to use for the `value` attribute of the option, and the 3rd parameter `"Text"` specifies the property to use for the options display text.

However, this is just pointless extra overhead (creating a 2nd `SelectList` from the original `SelectList`) and the last parameter `Model.Priority` is ignored when binding to a property.

Instead the 2nd example can be simply

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Priority, new []
{
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "1. Priority" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "2. Priority" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "3. Priority" }
})
```